# How to parse an object passed by an AJAX?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I made an Ajax POST request into my Laravel function however i am facing this result:

```
<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style')
```

This happens when i **die and dump** my data so as to see what i get from ajax request. I have this jquery method:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }

});

$('#save-person').on('click', function() {
    let first_name = $('#first_name').val();
    let middle_name = $('#middle_name').val();
    let third_name = $('#third_name').val();
    let family_name = $('#family_name').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: urlReq+"/api/employee/customize",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            first_name: first_name,
            middle_name: middle_name,
            third_name: third_name,
            family_name: family_name,
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(dataResult){
            console.log(dataResult);
            let data = dataResult;

            if(data.statusCode==200){
                $("#success").show();
                $('#success').html('Data added successfully !');                        
            }
            else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
                alert("Error occured !");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and on my php method i have this:

```
public function customize_store(Request $request){
    //dd($request->first_name);
    $input = $request->all();

    dd($input);

    return response()->json(['Person'=>$input]);
}
```

which result to `<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx =...` but my input are also present there that looks like this:

```
#<span class=sf-dump-protected title="Protected property">parameters</span>: <span class=sf-dump-note>array:15</span> [<samp>
      "<span class=sf-dump-key>first_name</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="7 characters">Michael</span>"
      "<span class=sf-dump-key>middle_name</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="6 characters">Sangga</span>"
      "<span class=sf-dump-key>third_name</span>" => <span class=sf-dump-const>null</span>
      "<span class=sf-dump-key>family_name</span>" => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="7 characters">Smith</span>"
```

How would i extract those data so that i can persist it on my database?

Comment: Can you please share the result of  dd($input);

Comment: Just `$request()->get('first_name');` or short `$request('first_name');` etc. What you are printing out is the html output of a `dd();`

Comment: The result is a script that looks like this: ```<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild || doc.documentElement.children[0]).appendChild(refStyle);``` and its too long but as i said it also includes my input data like, ```first_name```, ```middle_name```, etc.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey i ```dd($request()->get('first_name'));``` but i always get ```<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump``` then at the last ```<pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-361626292 data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class=sf-dump-str title="5 characters">Smith</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-361626292")</script>```.

Comment: Try with `var_dump($request()->all()); die();`

Comment: By the way, what is the value of `urlReq` in jQuery?

Comment: I get ```500 (Internal Server Error)```

Comment: ```urlReq``` value is ```127.0.0.1:8000```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this code.. check the URL, Routes on which you are sending your
>   data..

```
public function addPersonData(Request $request){
     $save_person = new Person(); // Initialize your model here..
     $save_person->first_name = $request->get('first_name');
     $save_person->middle_name = $request->get('middle_name');
     $save_person->third_name = $request->get('third_name');
     $save_person->family_name = $request->get('family_name');
     $save_person->save();
     return 'ok';     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it. First add a name to your route (see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes)) and the ajax part in your jQuery (assuming you use a form to submit the user data):

in your Route.php add:

```
Route::post('api/employee/customize', 'PersonController@customize_store')->name('api.employee.customize');
```

Your jQuery ajax request:

```
$('#save-person').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let first_name = $('#first_name').val();
    let middle_name = $('#middle_name').val();
    let third_name = $('#third_name').val();
    let family_name = $('#family_name').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('api.employee.customize') }}",
        type: "POST",
        data: { first_name, middle_name, third_name, family_name },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);

            if(data.status === 'success'){
                $("#success").show();
                $('#success').html('Data added successfully !');
                //the person's details are in data.person.first_name etc  
                //you already knew that, but added is the new data.person.id you may use                  
            }
            else {
                alert("Error occured !");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and your controller, assuming the model linked to this data is Person:

```
public function customize_store(Request $request){
    $person = new Person($request->all());
    if ($person->save()) {
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'person'=>$person]);
    }

    return response()->json(['status' => 'fail']);
}
```

Comment: I got this one: ```vendors.min.js:2 POST http://10.0.3.35:8000/contract/%7B%7B%20route('api.employee.customize')%20%7D%7D 405 (Method Not Allowed)```

Comment: I got it. It's a pure js file. Ok, then just add the url, but without urlReq+

Comment: I still get the same result.